# App List recyclerview check box changing state

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I made an app that have a list of all installed app in your device and I added a checkbox to the recyclerview to select an app on the list(I'm going to use this app as a base fo an app blocker). The problem is that the checkbox state always change when scrolling up/down. ex. I checked facebook then I scrolled down and when I scrolled up facebook is unchecked and sometimes a random app is checked.

here are my codes:

ApkInfoextractor:

```
public class ApkInfoExtractor {

    Context context1;

    public ApkInfoExtractor(Context context2){

        context1 = context2;
    }

    public List<String> GetAllInstalledApkInfo(){

        List<String> ApkPackageName = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED );

        //Information that is returned from resolving an intent against an IntentFilter
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context1.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0);

        for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList){
            ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;

            if(!isSystemPackage(resolveInfo)){

                ApkPackageName.add(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
            }
        }
        return ApkPackageName;
    }

    public boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo resolveInfo){
        return ((resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);
    }

    public Drawable getAppIconByPackageName(String ApkTempPackageName){
        Drawable drawable;

        try{
            drawable = context1.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(ApkTempPackageName);
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    public String GetAppName(String ApkPackageName){

        String Name = "";
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
        PackageManager packageManager = context1.getPackageManager();

        try {

            applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApkPackageName, 0);

            if(applicationInfo!=null){
                Name = (String)packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo);
            }

        }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Name;
    }
}
```

AppsAdapter:

```
public class AppsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context context1;
    private List<String> stringList;

    public AppsAdapter(Context context, List<String> list){
        context1 = context;
        stringList = list;
    }

    //viewholder initialized
    @Override
    public AppsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view2);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    private SparseBooleanArray sba = new SparseBooleanArray();

    //DATA IS BOUND TO VIEWS
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,final int position){

        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        ApkInfoExtractor apkInfoExtractor = new ApkInfoExtractor(context1);
            final String ApplicationPackageName = (String) stringList.get(position);

        //calling apps name and icon
        String ApplicationLabelName = apkInfoExtractor.GetAppName(ApplicationPackageName);
        Drawable drawable = apkInfoExtractor.getAppIconByPackageName(ApplicationPackageName);

        //setting app name and icon for every card
        viewHolder.textView_App_Name.setText(ApplicationLabelName);
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        //saving states of the checkbox
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sba.put(position, !sba.get(position));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(sba.get(position));

    }

    //viewholder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public CardView cardView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView_App_Name;
        public CheckBox checkBox;

        public ViewHolder (View view){

            super(view);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chckbox);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            textView_App_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Apk_Name);
            //textView_App_Package_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Apk_Package_Name);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return stringList.size();
    }
}
```

I've tried many solutions from google and none of them worked for me. So a detailed answer is going to be helpful (sample codes or other references are much appreciated.)

Comment: using iteam class and set and get method use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of SparseBooleanArray you can use Set

```
    HashSet<Integer> selection = new HashSet<>();
```

in onBind method use following, also use tagging instead of making position final

```
//saving states of the checkbox
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                if (selection.contains(pos))
                    selection.remove(pos);
                else 
                    selection.add(pos);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(selection.contains(position));
```

Comment: Upon further checking this doesn't work. When I run the app for the frst time it saved the sate but when i try it again the bug is back. edit: Now it's working properly. I dont know what is happening to my app.

Comment: Instead of notifying whole list .i.e. notifyDataSetChanged()
Notify only single item by calling notifyItemChanged(pos);

Comment: Remove thid line also
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: Now it's having a bug that one of the checked item is getting stuck on the screen(the chrome is following me) and sometimes a checkbox unchecked its self immediately.

Comment: Okay ill try removing that line

Comment: I think that solves the problem! can I have your email? so that I can contact when I encounter a problem with this again?

Answer (score 0):

I also occurred that problems past 2 years. But I overcome that problems by using `HashMap`. Save the boolean where clicked item on `Hash Map`. get from `HashMap` from `onBindViewHolder`

You Can Reference My [ConsistantRecylerAdapter](https://github.com/BannerCoe/ConsistantRecylerAdapter/blob/master/MyAdapter.java)

Answer (score 0):

Change your view holder to

```
         public ViewHolder (View view){

            super(view);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chckbox);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            textView_App_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Apk_Name);
            //textView_App_Package_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Apk_Package_Name);
           this.setIsRecyclable(false);
        }
```

The statement:

```
 this.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

This is just workaround, this may prevent recycler view not to reuse cell

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the exact same issue and fixed after so much of research. Reason for this is being in recycle view each time list is scrolled list items get recycled (gets created again ) hence losing its instance, views like Checkbox doesn't hold its data, unlike textview or edittext.

You can try following the way to fix this :

on click of checkbox save the value in the model class and inside onCreate check whats there in the JSON model class and assign to the checkbox

onCreate :

```
if(model.isChecked)) {
    checkbox.setChecked(true);

}else{
checkbox.setChecked(false);

}
```

and then when on checkbox clicked :

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
       model.setIsChecked(isChecked);
    }
```

I'm sure this will fix your problem.